# Which area-of-effect spell is able to drain/repurpose those spells cast in the area?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, content-identification

I remember finding a spell that now eludes me. It affected an area and any time someone in that area tried to cast a spell, the spell failed and the spell level was stored. When enough levels were stored, a predetermined spell was cast.

I seem to recall its name being weird, sounding more science than magic.

Comment: Do you remember where you saw it, or how official it was? How certain are you that it was a spell?

Comment: Absolutely official, and absolutely a spell. I had worked out the price of lining a place with a permanent version for an official-only game. The purpose was an one-way antimagic field, since nobody inside could cast but those outside could cast at them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it, Energy Transformation Field, Spell Compendium p80!

> You create a lingering zone of transformative magic that absorbs magic energy from magic items or spellcasting and uses it to power another spell tied to that location.[...]
>
> The field absorbs the magic of spells cast, spell-like or supernatural abilities that are activated, and magic items used within its dimensions.[...]
>
> An energy transformation field has a single spell linked to it. When the field has absorbed spell levels equal to the spell level of its linked spell, it automatically casts that spell at a point within the field designated by you at the time of the casting of the field.[...]

Comment: You should add a quote of the spell description or something so it's clear how it answers your (own) question and meets the criteria you remembered - that way it may be of use to others as well.

Comment: Good idea! How much can I safely quote without copyright issues?

Comment: Related metas: [Can non-open-license rules be discussed, or not?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6043/can-non-open-license-rules-be-discussed-or-not), [Is there any reason why quoting a D&D 5e spell in its entirety would not qualify as “fair use”?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8746/is-there-any-reason-why-quoting-a-dd-5e-spell-in-its-entirety-would-not-qualify), [Should we be including a whole copyrighted stat block?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6542/should-we-be-including-a-whole-copyrighted-stat-block)

Comment: Basically, include just as much information as you need to explain/support your answer. You shouldn't quote every part of the spell description if all that's relevant is one sentence, for instance. You can also paraphrase/summarize the context instead of quoting if you're worried about excessive quoting.